# SharpDevelop: windows 8 64 bits not running .exe

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit, sharpdevelop

I have developed a simple application using SharpDevelop running in a Windows Vista 32 bits operating system.
After generating the .exe file, it is not running in a Windows 8 64 bits operating system. In the project properties, I have tried with any 'target CPU' option with no result.
Is there any additional step I need?

Comment: Please show the error message you are getting.

Comment: I am not getting any error. When I double click the .exe file, my mouse cursor keep spinning and the application simply doesn't run.

Comment: Check the Windows event log for errors.